# React-Router throws Invariant Violation on setState() in ajax call

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to find a tricky error that I'm experiencing with react-router. For some reason, setting the state of one of my child components in a top-level page route causes the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Missing "userId" parameter for path "/user/:userId"
```

This error happens regardless of whether or not I am navigating to that path. My routes look this:

```
var routes = (
  <Routes>
    <DefaultRoute handler={LoginPage} />
    <Route name="login" handler={LoginPage} />
    <Route name="home" handler={HomePage} />
    <Route name="category" path="/category/:category" handler={CategoriesPage}/>
    <Route name="profile" path="/user/:userId" handler={ProfilePage}/>
  </Routes>
);
```

And my ajax call looks like this:

```
var Feed = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { feedItems: [] };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: '/api/transactions',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(transactions) {
      this.setState({ feedItems: transactions });
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
  });
},

....
```

This Feed is generated on a bunch of pages, including the HomePage and the ProfilePage. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how the :userId parameter could be related to the Ajax call in the feed, but that's where the stack trace leads me. Any help with what is going on here would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: Found the problem. My mongo database was out of date (model schemas changed), which was causing a host of problems, bubbling up to this Invariant Violation. I'm still not entirely sure how the two were related, but deleting old objects fixed the problem.

Comment: Are you using the [Navigation mixin](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/mixins/Navigation.md) anywhere?

Comment: Is the component still / already mounted when the "success" callback is called ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what was wrong and what you fixed? I am running into this as well.

Comment: When I posted this question, I was pretty confused about how to use React-Router with ReactJS. That invariant violation always comes from not passing in the parameter to the link. In my case, I think this was because my user was becoming corrupt, which meant that user._id was null, and so there was no userId passed to the url. Could you provide more info about your issue?

Comment: @ritmatter Thank you VERY much. That solved it. Took me 3 hours ...

Comment: @ritmatter I'll post an answer to this with a link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks, @ritmatter for solving this yourself !
Just as a reference, here the answer with a link to the docs.

Remember in **all** your **react-router** `<Link>` elements you have in your code, to include the `params` object for links pointing to a parameterized route:

```
<Link to="BillingInfo" params={userId:"user876718236"}>Your Billing Information</Link>
<!-- linking to /user876718236/billing-info -->
```

Have a look here for details: [react-router/Link](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link)

**UPDATE** [2015-03-29] corrected JSX param braces. Thanks to @Akay.

Comment: Correct syntax params={{userId:"user876718236"}}

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: v1.0 (November 2015)**

Named paths are no longer supported, you link to full paths. String templates in ES6 are handy for this:

```
// v0.13.x
<Link to="user" params={{userId: user.id}}>Mateusz</Link>

// v1.0
<Link to={`/users/${user.id}`}>Mateusz</Link>
```

From [Changelog: Links](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md#links).